# How to have site default homepage point to index.jsp?

Tags: jsp, ftp, hosting, cpanel

Noob here as far as uploading my first jsp site to ftp.
So I copied all files to public_html.
It's still pointing to index.html as the home page.
Do I have to delete index.html?
Is there a delay on seeing results on this?
I restarted shared tomcat via cpanel and it gave me a HTTP Status 404.
Do I have to contact hosting?

Any help would be great. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's the server configuration that prefers index.html over indes.jsp. I would suggest leaving an empty index.html (in case the server settings is reset and the browsing mode is on, the users would still not be able to see the contents of your directory) and looking for a server setting where you could specify index.jsp as a default site. You can also make a permanent redirect from index.html to index.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

The servers will always give ***high preference*** for **index.html** file over *index.jsp*, *index.php*, *index.asp*. 
 So if you want to use the other extension instead of **html** just delete the **index.html** file. 
Then the server will **automaticaly load the index.jsp or index.php or index.asp** files.